# ImportError: No module named matplotlib in IDLE

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I want to import matplotlib in IDLE. The following error occurs:

```
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

I use mac, the PATH of python in my bash_profile is:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Days ago I tried to uninstall python from my mac, so I am not sure if I just damaged built-in python.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you install matplotlib?

Comment: I use sudo easy_install matplotlib to install it. And in the shell using python a.py it works fine. But still cannot find module in IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you can look into.

- Python env variable for path is PYTHONPATH not just PATH. Change that.
- Run this command and see the path indeed includes what you need.

  ```
  $ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
  ```

Comment: Actually I found my matplotlib module in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python. How can I add it into the path file?

Comment: Just like you did earlier. But use PYTHONPATH instead of PATH

Comment: Just a reference, the command works in windows, but need to change the single ' to double ''.